Can i create a SharePoint online site which is accessible to any user (anonymous user)
Can i create a SharePoint online site which is accessible to any user (anonymous user)? is other word to create a public facing site-like using SharePoint online?
Thanks

It's not possible anymore (since 2018) to open SharePoint Online site to anonymous users.
As an alternative, you can:

Use Power Pages which allows anonymous user;
Use SharePoint Online with external users (users are not part of your organization, but managed as guests and authenticated in your Entra ID).

Source: SharePoint Online Public Websites to be discontinued
Related: How to make my SharePoint home page accessible to the public and profile page secured with login?

i thought there might be an update on this
